# Consider the sequence ${f_n}$ with $n \ge 2$, defined on $[0,1]$ by

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the sequence ${f_n}$ with $n \ge 2$, defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$f_n(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
n^2x, &0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n} \\ 
2n - n^2x, &\frac{1}{n} < x \le \frac{2}{n} \\
0, &\frac{2}{n} < x \le 1
\end{array}
\right.$$

a. Sketch the graph of $f_n$ for $n = 2, 3,$ and $4$

b. Prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0$ for each $x \in [0,1]$

c. Show that $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx = 1$ for all $n = 2,3,...$

I'm not sure on how to sketch a graph for a). Would I be right in having 3 sections for $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n} < x \le \frac{2}{n}$, and $\frac{2}{n} < x \le 1$ and then evaluating $f_n(x)$ for $n = 2, 3,$ and $4$ so that there's 3 graphs within each section? I'm also not sure how to do b) and c) as well. I'm just learning pointwise limits so I'm not familiar with these yet, so any hints/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your approach for part a) seems right. Once you've drawn the pictures, perhaps you'll see how to do part b).

Answer (score 4):

This is the classical counterexample given to show that norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_{\infty}$ aren't equivalent over $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$, because the family $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ and $||f_n||_1=1$, but there not exists any $m>0$ such that 
$$m||f_n||_{\infty} \leq ||f_n||_{1}\leq ||f_n||_{\infty}$$  To show that suppose that this constant exists, we would have that $m\leq \frac{1}{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, but that's not possible.

a) The graph of the functions $f_n$ is zero in everywhere except an isosceles triangle with basis $[0,2/n]$ and high $n$.

(b) Easy once you did (a). Fix the point $x$ and see what happens with the limit.

(c)$\int_0^{1} f_n(x)=(2/n).(n/2)=1$ (Area of the triangle)

Comment: While this may be true, I don't see how it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

a) Note that for the first two pieces only have a single power of $x$, so the graphs of these pieces are straight lines so, in order to graph these parts, it is enough to know where they begin and end.

b) As $n$ gets bigger, what happens to the three pieces? Which one gets bigger? If you fix $x$, can you guarantee that it will eventually be in this piece (i.e. for a big enough value of $n$)?

c) Once you draw the graphs in a), you will realise that the area between the graph and the $x$-axis is easy enough to calculate without the need to do any integration.

Comment: For a), for $f_2$ would the 2 lines I'd be drawing be $4x$ and $4-4x$ inside the appropriate sections? Just wanted to make sure I'm doing this right

Comment: For $n = 2$, that is correct.

Comment: For b) $n^2x$ gets bigger. If I fix x between $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$, then the most it could be is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2*\frac{1}{n} = n$. Then for $\frac{1}{n} < x \le \frac{2}{n}$, I'd have $\lim_{n\to\infty}2n - n^2*\frac{2}{n} = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}2n - n^2*\frac{1}{n} = n$.. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't make myself clear. When I said which one gets bigger, I meant which one of the three pieces ($[0, \frac{1}{n}], [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}], [\frac{2}{n}, 1]$) gets bigger, I wasn't referring to the value of the function on each of those pieces. You have to be careful with taking limits as the function value at $x$ can be given by different pieces as $n$ gets larger. For example, $f_2(0.4) = 4 - 4(0.4)$ using the first piece, $f_3(0.4) = 6 - 9(0.4)$ using the second piece, $f_4(0.4) = 8 - 16(0.4)$ using the second piece, and then $f_n(0.4) = 0$ for $n \geq5$ using the third piece.

Comment: Maybe think of this. The graphs you've drawn in a) should be triangles. What happens to the positions of these triangles as $n$ gets bigger?

Comment: I don't think I drew it well enough. http://postimg.org/image/b1uvzlzpr/ I guess I can kind of see triangles in there. $[0, \frac{1}{n}]$ is the one that's getting bigger as n gets larger. Would that mean it goes towards $\infty$ and $[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}]$ goes towards negative $\infty$ so they cancel each other out to $0$?

Comment: Careful, you're drawing the linear parts beyond their domain. You should only draw the function $4x$ for $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, $4-4x$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, etc. If you do that, the graph of $f_n$ will be a triangle with base $[0, \frac{2}{n}]$ and a peak at $\frac{1}{n}$ of height $n$. [Here](http://postimg.org/image/j5ny5x50h/) is a graph of the first two functions.